# cxxfunction error message, inline R-package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to reproduce an R example based in R help. 
This is an example for cxxfunction from inline package.

```
require(Rcpp)

require(inline)

# Rcpp plugin
if( require( Rcpp ) ){

fx <- cxxfunction( signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric" ) , '
    return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) ) ;
', plugin = "Rcpp" )
fx( 2L, 5 )

    ## equivalent shorter form using rcpp()
fx <- rcpp(signature(x = "integer", y = "numeric"),
               ' return wrap( as<int>(x) * as<double>(y) ) ; ')

}
```

I got this message:

`Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:
running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" ....`

And in addition:

`Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/bin/i386/R CMD SHLIB file3a86e316ef8.cpp ...`

I'm using:

platform   i386-w64-mingw32  and R-3.0.3

Comment: Why not use [Rcpp Attributes](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf)?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, it works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin said, its easier to use attributes. The attribute `// [[Rcpp::export]]` does all the work for you.

With the current versions on `R` and `Rcpp` installed create a file called `test.cpp` to put this code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double fx(int x, double y){
    return x*y;
}


/*** R
fx(2L,5)
fx(2L,5.1)
*/
```

Then in a `R` session run: `Rcpp::sourceCpp('test.cpp')`

That should work, if you have followed the instructions for installing `R`, `R-tools` and set `PATH` variables (if on windows) correctly.

Comment: No problem. I noticed you are not using the most recent packages/R. This is always recommended - as functionality can change (often for the better!)